# Google Chrome Extension integration testing with Chrome API

Tags: unit-testing, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, integration-testing

I've developed a Google Chrome extension. How can I test it ? It is straight forward if there are only plain javaScript. But here in my methods there are lot of Chrome API references available. It is not possible to do  unit testing as well.

So how can I test my extension with those API features. ?

Comment: It's possible to do unit testing, you need to use DI to inject API methods you need so you can mock them externally (as you would working on any other platform or anything else, it's also good practice to be sure of the dependencies of things).

Comment: What I'm trying to say here - is that there is nothing special about testing a chrome extension, tis' exactly like testing any other type of software.

Comment: I recommend using "Extension Reloader", it's will help you reload the extension and test it

Answer (score 2):

Use DI to inject API methods so that you can work on any other platforms.